# Any Windows file explorer which enables custom file order?

Tags: windows, file-management, workflow

Could you please recommend any file explorer software for Windows which allows user to modify order of each file manually? For example, drag a file to the position between two other files, or to the first position among all files in the same folder. Currently Windows 10 explorer only allows the files to be sorted by a file property like name, date created, and so on.

The reason I want to do this is that I want to sort files according to their priority. In the document folder, I want to put documents I want to read earlier in some former positions.

It would be best if the file order is stored as a file in the folder, because I share a folder on two PCs by Google Drive synchronization. If the file order is stored in this way, then when I modify the order on one PC, the new order would be saved on Google Drive, and so saved on the other PC by Google Drive synchronization.

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Welcome 李東翰 and thank you for the great question.  I'm interested to read answers to you question as well.  What I currently do is sort by filename, and preface filenames with an underscore that I want to appear at the very top of the list. I then preface filenames with numbers for other files (in numerical order of priority).  It's not perfect (reordering can be a bit of a pain), but it is a workaround.

Comment: BTW, I added a tag and changed the `windows-10` tag to `windows` because I can't think of any reason such software would not work any recent (or future) version of Windows.  If you can think of why such software would only work on Windows 10, please advise and revert my tag change. :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Yes, modifying file names works, but when you want to insert a file between 3.pdf and 4.pdf without having to rename 5.pdf, 6.pdf, ... and 19.pdf, you would have to make a name like 3.1.pdf. 

When you want to put a file between 3.pdf and 3.1.pdf, you have to make a name like 3.1.1.pdf. As this kind of names accumulate, the file list becomes messy, and it would be more and more troublesome to make a new name when you want to move a file.

Comment: Yes, I agree completely!  It can get to be a pain (and that's why I love your question!).  When I anticipate many reorderings, I use 2-5 digit numbers, and leave numerical gaps between each filename.  It makes things much easier, but not it's not a perfect solution.  Another technique I sometimes use is taking advantage of the amazing bulk file renamer in FreeCommander, which can add incrementing numbers to filenames.  It is available here: https://freecommander.com/

Comment: As an OT aside, I'm trying to see what type/brand of piano is being played (by you?) in your nice profile photo.  May I ask, what piano is it?

Comment: Ha, it's me playing, but the piano wasn't mine, so I don't remember its brand. If you're interested in my playing you can take a look at my YouTube videos. I'm amateur, so please don't expect much.

https://youtu.be/uicMQPI0p7k

Comment: I suggest asking in the forums of XYplorer and Directory Opus.

Comment: I watched you playing the piano.  You play wonderfully!  I enjoyed your selection as well.  Thank you!